# Good way to licensing Magento 2 extension for selling

Tags: magento2, extensions, licensing

I am creating some extension for magento 2, I would like to put some extension as Paid extension on my store,but Still one who purchase it I want to give them plain PHP code (means I don't want to encrypt it).
I want to use some license key stuff, 
can Any one will help me how can I achieve this ?

Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you release it as open source **there is no way** to stop someone trying to hack your licensing system.

If you do not care about this possibility, you can achieve it using a key based on the website domain name of something similar. I am thinking to an md5 algorythm.

Otherwise, but depends on what you are going to develop, you may keep a piece of logic in your server and let the extension use it by a SOAP call.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please explain me how can I achieve license key feature with magento ?